# DB2DataAdapter.Fill(dataset) throws error "SQL0901N (Reason "CPF4273".) SQLSTATE=58004"

Tags: db2, dataadapter

My application is Dot Net based.I am using VS My application uses IBm DB2 at its backend.
My Query is

```
SELECT A, B FROM SERVER.D WHERE A IN 
    (SELECT C FROM SERVER.E WHERE X = '01OBPP' AND Y= 'U' AND Z= '1')
```

A,B,C,X,Y,Z-COLUMN NAME, SERVER- SERVER NAME, D AND E -TABLE NAME

PFB the code-

```
DB2DataAdapter dbAdapter = null;
DB2Connection dbConn = null;
DB2Command dbCommand;
DataSet dsReturnDataSet  ;              
dbConn = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) dbConn.Open();
dsReturnDataSet.Clear();

dbCommand = GetCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = queryString;
dbCommand.Connection = dbConn;
dbAdapter = new DB2DataAdapter((DB2Command)dbCommand);
dbAdapter.Fill(dsReturnDataSet);
return dsReturnDataSet;
```

The GetCommand() method has the following statement

```
DB2Command dbCommand; 
dbCommand = null;
dbCommand = new DB2Command();
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 30;
return dbCommand;
```

While it hits the line 'dbAdapter.Fill(dsReturnDataSet);' it stucks there for a very long time and after that it throws the error

> "ERROR [58004] [IBM][AS] SQL0901N  The SQL statement failed because of
>   a non-severe system error. Subsequent SQL statements can be processed.
>   (Reason "CPF4273".)  SQLSTATE=58004"

Please provide some pointers.
i will be very grateful if any one can give some pointers as to hoW to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database log. There should be a `db2diag.log` file in the `db2dump` directory under the instance's `sqllib` directory. Search this file for the above error and it should contain the root cause (that non-severe system error) that it refers to.

Comment: Hi inflagranti, Thanks for the update. I found out SQLLIB but I couldn't find the db2diag.log. i did some surfing and found out that my DIAGPATH is empty and diaglevel is 3. ANy pointer as to where should I look or should I change the diagpath to some local place and re run the Query as to log the defect in the db2diag.log//

Comment: @Ayoti: You have to probably restart the DB2 service for that change to become active. I would not set the diaglevel above 3, as it will just fill your log. Check the documentation ( 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000299.html) for more information.

Comment: Because of `(Reason "CPF4273".)`, it seems that this is a remote DB2 for i database. As such, there will be no "db2diag.log" nor any "db2dump directory" nor any "instance's sqllib directory". The "CPF4273" is a generic indication that an error happened and that the joblog should be examined to see all previously logged messages.